# Programming Language most relevant to the Financial sector?

Tags: programming-languages, financial

I am a freshman in college and doing a software engineering/ finance double major. I've been learning programming on my own and have a good bit of familiarity with php by now. I was wondering what you guys think the most relevant programming language is for financial/investment banking use?

I have read this thread: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/13109/books-on-developing-software-for-financial-markets-investment-banks

I want to start learning/reading up on a language (the basics not financial/quant stuff) to set a foundation for the future financial/quant stuff.

Comment: I say this only half jokingly: **COBOL** [:)](http://jobsearch.monster.com/PowerSearch.aspx?q=COBOL&rad=20&rad_units=miles&indid=21&indid=38&tm=60)

Comment: I have work in finance and we used Java and C#. It all depends on **sensitivity** of the project, and what is **demanded**. For example security, reliability, flexibility etc.

Comment: I've noticed that functional languages are making their way into the financial sector, especially OCaml. Extra reading: http://www.janestreetcapital.com/minsky_weeks-jfp_18.pdf

Comment: Functional programming is suited for financial calculations like quantiative finance. Try F#, I hear it's getting more and more popular in the finance sector http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsyme/archive/2011/01/12/f-for-energy-trading-and-energy-portfolio-optimization.aspx

Comment: Consider also [Q/KDB+](http://kx.com/Products/kdb+.php), depending on where you want to work.

Comment: Scala, the functional programming language based on JVM. It's beautiful and very powerful, cross platform and you can utilize the very rich APIs written with Java or other languages on JVM.

Comment: Something to consider - the most important thing to land a job at a bank as a fresh grad is not the language on your resume.  Banks train fairly well.  Getting a summer Internship at the bank you want is the most important thing.

Comment: Can you use update your choosen answer relevent to 2022

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Working in the financial sector myself (albeit, in Australia), the languages I've seen used commonly among the other institutes I've talked with are

- **Anything .NET (C#, ASP, etc)**
- **Java**
- **C++**

Database knowledge will also come in very handy for you. Try learning some dialect of **SQL** like MS SQL or Oracle.

I know there are quite a few small institutes that also use **multivalued DBs** for their core transaction systems. This means something like

- **UniData/UniBasic**
- **UniVerse/UniBasic**
- **jBase**

If you are really interested in learning specific languages that you can directly use for a job, my advice would to peruse the job adverts in the local area where you want to get a job to get a feel what the financial institutes there are using specifically.

However, 2 things to note from this are:

- What skills they are looking for now could change by the time you graduate
- It doesn't matter that much. Learn the fundamentals and you should be able to pick up whatever you need.

Comment: I second the vote for learning SQL especially if your interested in high-frequency trading.

Comment: No problem @NoviceCoding

Comment: Excellent list. Also needs VBA and/or Excel in there too. I separate the two, because it's a mix of Excel VBA and then worksheet stuff like VLookups

Comment: Hello @DanMcGrath , please update your answer relevent to this 2022 or 50 years later.   I want to know what programming langauge is used for financial trading, paypal financial pay, and every enterprise industry langauge for this. Thank you

Answer (score 6):

It's a VERY broad field, but some things to consider...

Building custom Front Office Interfaces - Java

Building package systems - Not language specific.  Murex, Calypso and Sophis are some of the technologies.

Maintaining legacy code - Java, C++, and (yes) even COBOL.

Front office trading analytics - VBA (Yes) and other scripting languages to a much lesser degree.

Low latency trading - C++

Quantitative analytics - C++

Integration - Java, XML, FPML (Financial Products Markup Language)

General - You need to know UNIX and SQL

Comment: +1 This seems the more complete answer. Am I wrong or you didn't mention any functional language?

Comment: I have never seen it for real work.  Perhaps once to solve an in house brain teaser.  I have seen scripting languages like Python here and there too.

Answer (score 3):

**Smalltalk**: JP Morgan's Kapital. From conversations I've had, many current or ex-Smalltalkers come from UBS, and a large percent of South Africa's Smalltalkers came from, or were taught by people from, Rand Merchant Bank, a large local investment banking firm.

**OCaml**: [Jane Street](http://www.janestcapital.com/technology/ocaml.php)

Answer (score 2):

I was once told by a managing director at Morgan Stanley that the future of financial programming would be dominated by Python -- to which I thought, "So says the man who never programs..."  The person to his immediate right was a black belt C++ coder who knew enough to hand optimize routines in Intel assembly (after obtaining 2 PhDs).

That aside, I'm sure that every shop is different.  However, we found it best to prototype in Matlab - most quants have a good math background and this is an easy enough language to pick up. Then all production code was rolled in C/C++ with customized front-ends for either Excel or their own, homebrew, high performance cluster software.

However, if I were to start my own fund, I'd substitute R for Matlab, because I spent countless hours (while on a first name basis with the only guy I'd trust) on the phone with Matlab tech support debugging their flexlm licensing and C++ interface.

Comment: Re: Python, interestingly, the U.S. Securities and Exchange Commission recently proposed a mandate that would require securities issuers to submit a computer program that maps the logic flow of funds, and that “this computer program be filed… in Python”. http://www.sec.gov/rules/proposed/2010/33-9117.pdf

Comment: Wow.  Had no idea.  Since I switch btw Ubuntu & Windows, I just can't take a language where whitespace (tabs vs. spaces) matters...

Comment: @MTibbits, what, Ubuntu doesn't have spaces? :)

Comment: @Benjol, Ubuntu has spaces, it must be windows that doesn't.

Comment: It all depends on what you want to achieve. I know several people in investement banks doing prototyping in Python using a Python-binding to their C++-library. Regarding describing trades in Python: several people mentioned back then, this is not a good idea, because you can not verify Python programs. A programming language in the ML-family would be a better fit.